# Intermittent login issues to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, asp.net

My website is an ASP.NET 2.0 website connecting to a SQL Express Database.

Every now and then I get the following error message when I load my site.

> Login Failed for Username 'MyUsername'.

Then on another time I get the following error message.

> A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The specified network name is no longer available.)

After pressing F5 a few times it will go away. It is very intermittent and it drives me nuts as the company hosting my website cant figure out why this is happening.

Then it works then it does not, then it does then it does not!

Any idea???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After just a server update it solved the damn issue, so it was just a server issue.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need a log of date/times this error happens. If possible, add logging to the asp.net app, so you have a log of the exact times this happens.

Step #1: Check the SQL Server ERRORLOG. The important thing is to see if there are any errors or other issues logged at the times the client app has a problem. The point is to see if the problem is in the SQL Server, or "above" that on the stack.

Step #2: Check the windows event log. This may be able to show if there is a system wide issue.

Those are the high level tests that should get you closer to the problem.